# Persist Database across "Clear Data" in Android?

Tags: android, database

I am working on an android application which requires a database to store the value from the app.

My requirement is that *I need the database not be cleared when the clear data option in the app is done*.

Anyone please suggest me the location where the database can be stored so that is not deleted when clear data option is used.

Comment: Do you mean store on phone (or) some where on your server?

Comment: i mean somewhere in the internal memory of the phone

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean the "Clear Data" from the Preferences->Apps menu.

I recommend you review your reasons for preventing this.

Hitting "Clear Data" would allow the user to reset the application as when newly installed, which really means recover from possible application errors you haven't thought about.

Comment: i knew the fact that clear data resets the app to a newly installed one. But my requirement is that the database should not be deleted from the device until the app is uninstalled

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data into mysql database and use server php to get data from android 
Try this [link](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/08/android-phpmysql-connection/)

Comment: i dont need that much complex tasks, Suggest me something that can be done in a easy but effective manner because i will store only one value in the database

Comment: LOL! you did not say that, then use sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Does storing on SD Card works for you?

Comment: ya... but what is the alternate for the device with no sd card

Comment: It appears that all data stored internal memory is erased with that option.

Comment: Not all data is erased ,only the data that are present in the package of the app is being deleted

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Verbosely, all data in the application data directory is erased.

Comment: i need to know that if there is any possibility of creating a new package other than the app package from the app in the internal memory of the device and store the database there

Comment: AFAIK app data storage directory is managed by android so you can't create package data folders.

Comment: is there any possibility to create a folder in the system directory